# Calling custom exe in ExitDialog

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I’m beginning with WiX and I have some trouble to customize ExitDIalog.

At first what I want:

- I want to create a setup for my application
- After setup I want to propose 2 choices :

  - Launch application (application.exe newly installed)
  - Launch an optional setup (my application require to install some drive depending of user’s camera)
- The optional setup is a .exe. It should be placed next to setup.msi but no copied in my application folder.

I created directories :

```
<Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
      <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="$(var.compagny)"/>
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" SourceName="Desktop"/>
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="COMPAGNYFOLDER" Name="$(var.compagny)">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.product)">            
          <Directory Id="fr" Name="fr"/>   
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

How can I add a reference to my .exe ? I did :

```
<Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="{2C26B191-6654-4405-8E78-F8B6EFEDC9FC}" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <File Id="uEye64_47100_WHQLexe" Source="./Resources/uEye64_47100_WHQL.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes" Compressed="no" Vital="no"/>
</Component>
```

But the `uEye64_47100_WHQL.exe` file is copied in INSTALLFOLDER (I don't want) and the setup mix the path with [application]/bin/Release (don't know with). In the log file there is :

> Failed to open the file:C:\dev\MyApplication\main\SetupProject\bin\Release\MyCompagny\MyProduct\uEye64_47100_WHQL.exe for computing its hash. Error:3

And I call the .exe like this (this file require elevated privileges)

```
<!-- Set checkbox for launch install uEye -->
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGUEYECHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch install uEye"/>
<CustomAction Id="SetExecUEye" FileKey="uEye64_47100_WHQLexe" ExeCommand="" Return="asyncNoWait" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred"/>

<UI>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Custom"/>      
  <Publish Dialog="MyExitDialog"
           Control="Finish" 
           Event="DoAction"                
           Value="SetExecUEye">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGUEYECHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
</UI>
```

How should I define my `uEye64_47100_WHQL.exe` to be called after setup but no copied in `INSTALLFOLDER` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to copy file to install location, just run it, you can include it as Binary source instead of component. This way, it is packed in installer, but is not deployed on installation (probably to some temp folder only).

```
<Binary Id="uEye64_47100_WHQLexe" SourceFile="./Resources/uEye64_47100_WHQL.exe" />
<CustomAction Id="InstalluEye64exe" BinaryKey="uEye64_47100_WHQLexe" ExeCommand=""  Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="no"/>
```

Comment: You save my day ! Wix gonna makes me crazy. One error to remove (ErrorCode 2762) and my setup will be done.

Comment: Is it possible to set the binary to be not compressed and not vital ? My setup.msi is 4ko, the optionnal.exe is 150Mo. Declaring as `Binary` make my setup.msi be 154Mo. At least my setup must be working without this file (only the checkbox will go in error)